# Is it possible for a Roslyn [Generator] to add attributes to a property / field / method / property?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'd like to be able to add a single `[FirstName]` to a property, and have a code generator add

```cs
[MinLength(1)]
[MaxLength(32)]
[Required]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Only if it's a partial declaration and your generator implements it.

Comment: What you could also do is generate a new class based off of the existing one. The generated class would have the desired properties and you could use that instead of the class you write.

Comment: @PauloMorgado but properties cannot be partial, can they?

Comment: Now that you mention it, no they can't. The only way, other than what @CollinAlpert said, is to change the IL after compilation.

Comment: until https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3412 is done you cannot because partial properties dont exist.  You could however make it not a property and instead be a private field then generate a property that is backed by the field and public.  Is slightly easier than the other options presented.